# jQuery: how do I replace part of original hyperlink with non-hyperlinked text?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a class, let's say `.check-status`, that is a text that has a hyperlink in it.

I have an event listener on click that is supposed to replace that text with a variable statusResponse and then say 'Check again'. So it would say something like 'Your status is pending. Check again'; but 'Check again' needs to be the original hyperlink and 'Your status is pending' should be regular text.

I know how to use something like the below:

```
$('.check-status').text(statusResponse).append(' Check again')
```

But that gives me everything as a hyperlink, and I only want the 'Check again' part to be that hyperlink.

How do I achieve that without creating new divs, etc?

Thanks!

Comment: Please share the `html` of the element of that class and the embedded hyperlink.

Comment: Also change `$('check-status')` for `$('.check-status')`

Comment: question of clarification: do you want the hyper link to only say "Check again"?

Comment: @AGE, thanks, it was correct in the original code, I was typing it out; just edited it in the question.

Comment: @trincot  It is inside a handlebarJS template. 

    <a class="check-status" href="#">Check your status.</a>

Comment: @indubitablee Yes, I want the hyperlink to only say 'Check again', but I want it to be prepended by the `statusResponse` text which will be changing as 'Check again' is clicked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var statusResponse = "Your status is pending.",
    customFlag = false;

$(".custom-btn").click(function(){
    if(!customFlag){
        customFlag = true;
        var checkStatus = $(".check-status");
        checkStatus.before(statusResponse + " ").text("Check again");
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button class="custom-btn">Click me</button>
<br/><br/>
<a class="check-status" href="#">Check your status.</a>
```

So what does this do?

1. First of all since we are reusing `$(".check-status")` so often it is preferable to have it in a var named `checkStatus`.
2. Using [before](http://api.jquery.com/before/) we take the text inside `checkStatus` and put it *before and outside* `checkStatus`.
3. The text that sits inside `statusResponse` is now placed inside the `checkStatus` object.
4. We only want this to occur once, so a flag is required.

Comment: I see what you did here, but I wanted the (non-hyperlinked) text part to be the `statusResponse` variable. Any ideas?

Comment: this is wonderful actually, but here are two problems:

1. It does not do anything with the statusResponse variable.

2. If I modify it to, say, be checkStatus.before(statusResponse + " ").text("Check again."), it actually keeps showing a new statusResponse content each time I click 'Check again' -- so I end up with a never ending string of them. 

Thanks for all your help!

Comment: @Eupatoria in that case we need to analyze your click event, I am going to modify again my answer stand by

Comment: @Eupatoria it's ready, take a look let me know if you need anything more

Comment: thank you so much! This was exactly what I needed. I would have not thought of the customFlag solution myself. Really, really appreciate you help

Comment: @Eupatoria You're welcome! keep in mind you can do whatever you need in terms of flags, or checking for the `statusResponse` not to be the same, etc. The best solution would be to find a way to have the `before` statement consistently overwriting, but that's another question altogether don't you think :-)

Answer (score 2):

As you want the hyperlink to only be on a part of the complete text, you'll need an anchor element only for that text, while the complete text should be formatted with your class. So proceed like this:

**HTML**

```
<span class="check-status"><a href="status.php" >Your status is pending</a></span>
```

**JavaScript**

```
var statusResponse = "Your status is pending. ";
var checkAgain = "Check again."
$('.check-status>a').before(statusResponse).text(checkAgain);
```

Here is [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/q581xbj7/) as demo.